# Is it possible to link Java method from Kotlin comment?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, comments

I have an Android project where Java and Kotlin files are mixed. I am writing a comment in one of the Kotlin files and I want to link some method in Java file.

**Is this possible? How?**

For Kotlin I do:

```
/**
*    [ResultMatcher.getCount]
*/
```

But when `ResultMatcher` is java class it doesn't work. I tried adding different symbols (`_`,`#`) and `.java` or `::class` but it didn't help.

Comment: have you tried with an @see comment tag?

Comment: @creekorful I did now, also doesn't work, but thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely `ResultMatcher` is not the full qualified name and you don't have an `import`.

Below works in IntelliJ, you can click on `size` and it will navigate to the method body:

```
import java.util.ArrayList

/**
 * [ArrayList.size]
 */
fun main() { }
```

and this also works:

```
/**
 * [java.util.ArrayList.size]
 */
fun main() { }
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you.